# Using auto as return type and return value nullptr in some cases

Tags: c++, c++14

If we have method with return type `auto`, but into the method we will return a new object or `nullptr`.
If I correctly understand when we return `nullptr`, it will create also new object through constructor.

Method is `With`.

Question is next:
Which type will be used in place of `auto`?
It will depend on type returning by `maybe` or not:
`maybe` is a function which returns `Maybe<T>`.
When we call first `With` returning type is `Maybe< Adress >`;
second step it may be `Maybe< Adress >` since is the type of object or `Maybe< std::string >` - it returns if context is not `nullptr`.

```
struct Address {
    string* house_name = nullptr;
};

struct Person {
    Address* address = nullptr;
};

template <typename T> struct Maybe;

template <typename T> Maybe<T> maybe(T* context)
{
   return Maybe<T>(context);
}

template <typename T>
struct Maybe {
    T* context;

    Maybe(T *context) : context(context) { }

    template <typename TFunc>
    auto With(TFunc evaluator)
    { 
        return context != nullptr ? maybe(evaluator(context)) : nullptr;
    }
 };

 ...

 void print_house_name(Person* p)
 {
    auto z = maybe(p)
    .With([](auto x) { return x->address; })
    .With([](auto x) { return x->house_name; })
    .Do([](auto x) { cout << *x << endl; });
 }


int main()
{
   //print_house_name(nullptr);

   Person p;

   print_house_name(&p); // nothing

}
```

Comment: The issue is not with the `auto` but with the `context != nullptr ? maybe(evaluator(context)) : nullptr`. The type of this expression is determined by the [rules for ternary conditionals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). Step 3 seems to be the one that applies here.

Comment: C++ already has a `Maybe`-like class `std::optional` that works both with value and pointers and has many handy syntax features.

Comment: Are you basically just asking what the type of that conditional operator expression is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which type will be used in place of `auto`?

The return type of your function is determined by the type of the expression in the single `return` statement. In your case the statement is:

```
return context != nullptr ? maybe(evaluator(context)) : nullptr;
```

The returned expression is a ternary operator whose two potential values have different types (`Maybe<C>`, for some class `C` not necessarily `T`, and `nullptr_t`). This is only well-formed if one of the types is implicitly convertible to the other. Normally `nullptr_t` converts only to/from other pointer types, so let's look at the implicit conversions defined for `Maybe` (there's only one):

```
Maybe(T *context) : context(context) { }
```

A pointer type can be converted to a `Maybe`. So `nullptr` gets converted to `C*` which then gets converted to a `Maybe<C>` object (whose context is null). Again, I'm using `C` instead of `T` because this type need not be the same template parameter that is part of the type of `*this`. The returned type is the same regardless of the value of `context`.

If you want to see this implicit conversion break, make the conversion to `Maybe` explicit, as in `explicit Maybe(T *context) : context(context) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

`auto` isn't magical. It it simply a placeholder that your compiler fills in with a concrete, deduced type. The end result is *exactly the same* as if you had written the deduced type manually.

"If I correctly understand when we return nullptr, it will create also new object through constructor". No. Returning `nullptr` does not call any constructors. It simply returns a null value of the appropriate type. No object is constructed.

"Which type will be instead auto" - The return tupe will be whatever the type of what you *actually* return *is*. And that can only ever be *one* specific type.

Comment: The ternary conditional will attempt to reconcile the `Maybe<T>` and `nullptr_t` by constructing a `Maybe<T>` from a `nullptr_t`. So a constructor does get invoked, but not as part of the `auto`; rather it is constructed as part of the `?:`.

Comment: When we return nullptr it will create object since we return by value. In your case should be next : auto*